# Converting .edf to .npy

Tags: python, numpy, european-data-format

I'm attempting to convert a .edf file to .npy file. I'm new to coding, but my basic understanding is that both files are arrays and I should be able create a script in python to convert the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the European Data Format? If so, you can use the [mne-python](https://martinos.org/mne/stable/index.html) library:

```
import mne.io
edf_raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(edf_fname, preload=True)
hz = 1 / (edf_raw.times[1] - edf_raw.times[0])
# If you wish to get specific channels and time:
edf_data, times = edf_raw[channels_indices, int(from_t * hz): int(to_t * hz]
# Or to get all the data:
edf_data, times = edf_raw[:, :]
```

Comment: Yes and thank you for the response. Using your method, I'm able to import the .edf file and save out with np.save('filename',times). This seems to work although the newly generated .npy file is about 6x the original .edf

Comment: Glad that I helped! If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it. You can also send me the edf file, and I can check if I can save it in a more compact way.

Comment: Hey Noam, re-working this, I was able to get a reduced .npy but it seems to be converting my .edf data incorrectly. Here's my manipulated code below: